# How to export unicode data into word document using php com

Tags: php, unicode, character-encoding, com

I am exporting unicode data using Php COM. I have written in top of my web page the below line:

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

But when I export the unicode data into a word document using Php COM, It is not coming properly like a unicode, Instood it is coming as shown below:

```
à²†à²¦à²¿à²¯à²²à³à²²à²¿ à²¦à³‡à²µà²°à³ à²†à²•à²¾à²¶à²µà²¨à³à²¨à³
```

I use the Php COM code to export the data to word document as below:

```
$unicode_data = "ಆದಿಯಲ್ಲಿ";
$word = new variant(com_get_active_object("word.application"));
$word->Selection->TypeText($unicode_data);
```

So please suggest me what else should be included to above code to get a unicode in correct format in the word document.

(From comment)

```
CREATE TABLE kan (
    id int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    content text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=31105 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Any Answers please...

Answer (score 1):

You wanted some Kannada text like 'ಆದಿಯಲ...'?

You should not have to mention "unicode" anywhere.

Your 'meta' and connection look correct.

Please go to [Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) and look at the recommended `SELECT .. HEX`.  Does the hex look something like this (but without spaces)?

```
E0B286 E0B2A6 E0B2BF E0B2AF
```

If so, it was stored correctly.  If not, then you have "double encoding" and the hex will be more like

```
C3A0 C2B2 E280A0 C3A0 C2B2 C2A6 C3A0 C2B2
```

utf8 E0B286   is Unicode  3206=x0C86 representing [ಆ] KANNADA LETTER AA

Comment: Yes, the Hex looks exactly like E0B286 E0B2A6 E0B2BF E0B2AF. So there is no problem in the way it is stored. I exported the same unicode data into word document using using http header method and it is exporting correctly but I want to achieve the same export  using php com method

Comment: Http header method is : <?php
    $unicodedata = "ಆದಿಯಲ್ಲಿ";
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=document_name.doc");
 
 echo "<html>";
 echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">";
 echo "<body>";
 echo "<b>".$unicodedata."</b>";
 echo "</body>";
 echo "</html>";
    ?> and it is exporting the unicode as it is

Comment: Hmmm...  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: But when i pass the same variable into PHP COM method then it is not  exporting in the right format: <?php $unicodedata = "ಆದಿಯಲ್ಲಿ"; $word = new variant(com_get_active_object("word.application"));
$word->Selection->TypeText($unicodedata); ?>

Comment: Only difference in these two methods i see is: http header method uses echo "meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">" which is making the export success. I want to achieve the same charset encoding in php com

Comment: A guess:  Something is mis-configured in the COM object.  (I know nothing about COM.)  Suggest starting a new Question with that code in your last comment.  (That is, leave MySQL out of the equation.)  Need to attract COM folks, not me (mysql folk).

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE : CREATE TABLE `kan` (
 `id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `content` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=31105 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: Any Answers please

Comment: I'm out of ideas from a MySQL side.  See my suggestion about starting a non-mysql question.